# Webforms CSRF prevention not working

Tags: security, webforms, csrf, csrf-protection

Using Webforms 4.5, and the code from the link below to prevent CSRF attacks. We aren't using Master pages so this same code is inlcuded in a Sitecore base layout.

https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf

This doesnt seem to prevent a CSRF attack as if we have a script outside of the site, it is able to post manipulated data to the site. We've added a view state (copied from web page) to this script.

This CSRF prevention code compares a token value set in the view state to an in-memory variable. 
However, as our script includes view state, it includes the view state variable and so this code doesnt produce an error as the view state variable matches the in-memory one.

I would expect this code to work as it's part of web forms Master pages... any ideas why it's not working for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CSRF attack is a write-only attack. For example,

1. Hacker sends out a million emails containing an "image" that actually links to `https://www.SomeBank.com/Transfer?Amount=1000&ToAccount=HackersAccount`
2. Some percentage of the million emails are opened
3. Some percentage of the users who open the emails are also logged into `www.Somebank.com`
4. When the image is "retrieved" the email client actually sends a request to the banking site and moves the money. The request succeeds because cookies for `www.SomeBank.com` are passively sent along with the request.

The CSRF token provides a piece of information that is not known and not knowable to the hacker. When the request is received without the token, the transfer is denied.

If the hacker has access to the page, and can read the token, the mechanism does not work, as you are seeing. Of course, if he has access to the page, you have bigger problems!

Comment: Thanks John. I understand what you are saying but the code linked to in my post compares a ViewState value to an in-memory value. If the hacker has that ViewState value in their html then they will be able to post to the site using that html .. dont see how the code linked to code can prevent this

Comment: Exactly. A CSRF mitigation does not protect against a hacker who has unfettered access to the page content. It only protects you from hackers who have the ability to submit blind requests from the browser. If they can access the page then the battle is already lost, which is why CSRF protection is useless without XSS protection.